# Does a Spring Boot Project that runs as a Jar needs a web.xml file?

Tags: spring-boot

As the title states.

I am migrating a Spring-MVC application that uses XML based Configuration.

I don't know where to move the filters located in the web.xml file to the new Spring Boot Project.

Comment: That's right, but I prefer to use Java instead of old xml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the annotation : `@ImportResource` for this
Find more details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-configuration-classes.html)

Comment: That's right, but I prefer to use Java instead of old xml configuration.

Comment: For using programmatic equivalent for moving filters in spring boot equivalent, you can configure `ServletContext` programmatically. That will require implementing `WebApplicationInitializer`. Override the `onStartup` method

`public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException{
container.addFilter("YourFilter1",YourFilter.class).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,false,"/*");
}`

A good explanation for the entire migration can be see [here](http://www.robinhowlett.com/blog/2013/02/13/spring-app-migration-from-xml-to-java-based-config/)

Answer (score 0):

You can define your filters using Java Configurations when using Spring Boot.

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-embedded-container), you only need to declare that filter as a Bean in a configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

@Bean
public Filter someFilter() {
return new someFilter();
 }
}
```

If for some reason "SomeFilter" is not a spring managed bean, or if you need to customize the filter behaviour, then you can register the filter using FilterRegistrationBean as follows

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

@Bean
public Filter someFilter() {
 return new someFilter();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration() {

    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(someFilter());
    return registration;
 } 

}
```

In case of multiple Filters you can specify the order using FilterRegistrationBean.setOrder() as mentioned [in the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/FilterRegistrationBean.html)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I registered my Interceptors using Java Configuration (no xml) this way.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    ControllerInterceptor controllerInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(this.controllerInterceptor).addPathPatterns(this.buildPaths());
    }

    private String[] buildPaths() {

        String paths[] = { "/api/example1/**", "/api/example2/**" };

        return paths;
    }
}
```